# allowing click jquery hide on a jquery ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a newbie trying to display a map for each of many entities on a community web site. Each entity has a unique ID.

The load is triggered by a jquery click of an image with a class code of "action"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center+.action").click(function(){
    $("#ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center").load("demo_test_maps.htm #ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center");
  });
});

<div id="ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<a href="#" class="action"><img src="images/map_20x12.jpg"></a>
```

The material being loaded includes an image with a class code "map-icon" that I was hoping would give me a handle to jquery hide.

```
<a href="#" class="map-icon"><img src="images/close_hover.png"></a>
```

I have been able to get the correct material to load into this test document. But, in the real world, this will be displayed in a layer on top of other displayed stuff, so I will need to allow the visitor to hide what was just loaded.

I don't know how to code this.

What do I need to change this code so that Jquery hide will take effect on the jquery Ajax loaded material in each case.

Comment: for starters, I think this `$("#ABC_...ement_Center+.action").click(func...` should be `$("#ABC_...ement_Center .action").click(func...` (+ -> space)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could set the event handler in the callback function of load() [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center+.action").click(function(){
    $("#ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center").load("demo_test_maps.htm #ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center", function(){
      $(".map-icon").click( function(){
         $("#ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center").hide();
      });
    });
  });
});

<div id="ABC_Seamless_Home_Improvement_Center"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<a href="#" class="action"><img src="images/map_20x12.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: I would use remove() instead of hide() so that the loaded div and the new event handler gets removed from the DOM completely. Otherwise repeated clicking of the load will lead to hidden divs piling up in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

For adding handlers to dymanically injected content, the best method is to use the jQuery `.on()` method ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) and passing a `selector` parameter.

So essentially you bind a click function to a containing element of some kind (which will always be in the DOM) and when this event click is triggered, it sees if the target element matches the selector you passed it (which then bubbled to your click handle). Example;

```
// bind click handler
$('#container').on('click', '.loaded', function(){
    // do something on click
    alert($(this).html());
});

// bind the AJAX load handler
$('#someButton').click(function(){
    //this func uses ajax to load html ito the container
});

<!-- initial HTML -->
<div id='someButton'>Click Me To load content</div>
<div id='container'>
    <!-- jQuery loads data via AJAX -->
</div>
```

Okay, so when you click the #someButton div, its loads the data using ajax (this function I've left out). Then it puts the HTML into the #continaer div so the HTMl now looks like this.

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='loaded'>content</div>
    <div class='loaded'>content1</div>
    <div class='loaded'>content2</div>
</div>
```

Now if you click the one of the three divs, their inner HTML will be alerted. What happens is you click on a .loaded div, the click event bubbles up to the #container which then causese the click handler at the top to file. As per the click handler, it looks to see if the selector you passed it ('.loaded') matches the target element of the bubbling click event, and if it does (which is does in this case) it executes the callback function.